# Map_dbl in R to replace for loop

Tags: r, loops, purrr

This is an easy question, but I had problems solving it so please don't laugh at me.

I'm given a task to re-create my own function for mean in R instead of using the in-built mean function.

The condition for my function is that I need to use map_dbl to handle any iteration in my function.

I know that `mean = (sum of all elements)/(number of elements)`

The question is, does anyone knows how to calculate the sum of all elements using map_dbl?

Comment: Mean is more a Reduce operation than a map : `x <- c(1:10); Reduce('+',x)/Reduce('+', T | x);`

Comment: @Waldi If my only option is to use map_dbl, how am I going to iterate through the list of elements?

Comment: could you provide your loop code so far?

Comment: assuming 

```x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)```
I want to find the sum of the elements in x
I am thinking of doing :
```counter <- 0 ```
```map_dbl(x, ~{counter <- counter + .x})```

Nonetheless, this gives me {1,2,3,4,5} instead of the 15 that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit overkill:

```
x <- c(1:10)
counter <- 0
mapsum <- map_dbl(x, ~{counter <<- counter + .x})
mapsum
[1]  1  3  6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
tail(mapsum,1)
55
```

As mentionned in comments, this works but sum/mean is a reduce operation, not a map operation.